# extending Backbone.Collection prototype

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, qunit

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219182/retrieve-element-from-backbone-collection-removen), I'm trying to augment Backbone.Collection with some custom methods. However, I'm getting some inconsistent behaviour between the console and the source.

Here's how the test looks

**HTML**

```
... 
<script type="text/javascript" src="./libs/underscore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./libs/backbone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./libs/backbone-extend.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="./qunit/qunit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./backbone-extend-tests.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

**backbone-extend.js**

```
Backbone.Collection.prototype.extract = function() {
    // placeholder to test binding
    return 'foo';
};
```

**backbone-extend-tests.js**

```
test('extending backbone', function () {
    ok(typeof Backbone.Collection.extract == 'function');
    console.log(Backbone.Collection.extract); // undefined
});
```

Is there something I'm missing? I've checked that all the source is loading

JFTR - this...

```
_.extend(Backbone.Collection, {extract:function(){return'foo';});
```

...works, just not using the prototype augmenting method. I'm just unsure why one method works and the other doesn't, given that the docs for Backbone [recommend](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-extending) prototype augmentation (although it specifically mentions Models). Guess I need to take a more detailed look under the bonnet...

**UPDATE:** 
 for posterity, placing this in the backbone-extend.js file...

```
 _.extend(Backbone.Collection.prototype, {
     extract : function (model) {
     var _model = model;
     this.remove(model);
     return _model;
 }
 });
```

... works

Comment: Wait are you trying to add a method to the class or to an instance of the class. Those aren't the same thing. And why aren't you using backbones build in `extend` if you are doing the latter?

Comment: I'm trying to add a method to the class, so that all collections have an "extract" method. If you take at my original question, I wanted a method that would give me back the item when calling Backbone.Collection.remove()

Comment: i'm not *entirely* sure you see what i mean

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are mixing up a few key concepts which is why you aren't seeing the behavior that you expect, which is more a fundamental javascript question and not entirely related to backbone.

Consider the following constructor:

```
var Klass = function() {};
```

You can invoke that constuctor using the `new` keyword to get an instance from that constructor.

```
var klassInstance = new Klass();
```

Now, lets say I wanted to add a method that was available to *all* of the instances that are derivied from that constructor. For that I can use the `prototype` object.

```
Klass.prototype.instanceMethod = function() { alert('hi'); };
```

Then I should be able to invoke that method using the following:

```
klassInstance.instanceMethod();
```

However, I can also add a *static* function – and I use the term loosely in this context – to the constructor itself, which can be invoked without having an instance.

```
Klass.staticMethod = function() { alert('yo!'); };
```

This method will be available directly off the constructor, but will *not* be available – directly – off of instances.

For example:

```
klassInstance.staticMethod == undefined
```

So what's really wrong with your test is that you are adding a method to the `prototype` – a method that will be available to all instances of that "class" – but in your test you are testing for a method directly on the "class" itself. Which is not the same thing.

---

An aside, though relevant, Backbone.js provides a built in mechanic to create "sub-classes" of thier built in types. This is the *static* `.extend()` method. This provides you a simple way to add your own functionality to the base Backbone classes.

In your case you would want to do something like:

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    extract: function() {
        // do whatever
    }
})
```

Then, you can create instances of your new classes, which will have an `.extract()` method on them by saying:

```
var coll = new MyCollection();
coll.extract();
```

---

### TL;DR;

Ultimately – back to your original question – if you want a method that will be available on all instances of a particular class, then your *test* is incorrect. You either need to new up an instance to test against:

```
test('extending backbone', function () {
    var col = new Backbone.Collection();
    ok(typeof col.extract == 'function');
});
```

Or check the `prototype` directly for a method – this is subtlely different in the fact that the `prototype` object is not the *only* for an object to get a method.

```
test('extending backbone', function () {
    ok(typeof Backbone.Collection.prototype.extract == 'function');
});
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to respond in such detail. I grok the difference between augmenting the prototype vs the instances - although the "static" method was new to me. Since I want to augment all Backbone collections, I need to augment it's prototype - not sure why extending the prototype manually didn't work, but using .extend did the trick...

Answer (score 0):

make sure `backbone.js` and `underscore.js` is fully loaded before doing the tests.

Comment: Hmmm, that was my first thought given that Backbone is a significanly larger file - so I simply appended my prototype work to the Backbone file itself. Still no luck - I may try and use require.js to make sure this is all queued up properly.